# Converting equation into Octave / Matlab code and a for loop

Tags: recurrence-relations, matlab, functional-equations, octave

I have an array of thousands of values I've only included three groupings as an example below:

*(amp1=0.2; freq1=3; phase1=1; is an example of one grouping)*

```
t=0;
amp1=0.2; freq1=3; phase1=1;   %1st grouping
amp2=1.4; freq2=2; phase2=1.7; %2nd grouping
amp3=0.8; freq3=5; phase3=1.5; %3rd grouping
```

The *Octave* / *Matlab* code below solves for *Y* so I can plug it back into the equation to check values along with calculating values not located in the array.

```
clear all
t=0;
Y=0;
a1=[.2,3,1;1.4,2,1.7;.8,5,1.5]
for kk=1:1:length(a1)
    Y=Y+a1(kk,1)*cos ((a1(kk,2))*t+a1(kk,3))
    kk
end
Y
```

These are the formulas I've tested but I'm not sure how to put it into a for loop that will work in an array of ***n groupings***:

```
phase1_test=acos(Y/amp1-amp3*cos(2*freq3*pi*t+phase3)/amp1-amp2*cos(2*freq2*pi*t+phase2)/amp1)-2*freq1*pi*t
phase2_test=acos(Y/amp2-amp3*cos(2*freq3*pi*t+phase3)/amp2-amp1*cos(2*freq1*pi*t+phase1)/amp2)-2*freq2*pi*t
phase3_test=acos(Y/amp3-amp2*cos(2*freq2*pi*t+phase2)/amp3-amp1*cos(2*freq1*pi*t+phase1)/amp3)-2*freq2*pi*t
```

$$\left[ {\it phase_1}=\arccos \left({{y}\over{{\it amp_1}}}-{{
 {\it amp_3}\,\cos \left(2\,{\it freq_3}\,\pi\,t+{\it phase_3}\right)
 }\over{{\it amp_1}}}-{{{\it amp_2}\,\cos \left(2\,{\it freq_2}\,\pi
 \,t+{\it phase_2}\right)}\over{{\it amp_1}}}\right)-2\,{\it freq_1}
 \,\pi\,t \right] $$

$$\left[ {\it phase_2}=\arccos \left({{y}\over{{\it amp_2}}}-{{
 {\it amp_3}\,\cos \left(2\,{\it freq_3}\,\pi\,t+{\it phase_3}\right)
 }\over{{\it amp_2}}}-{{{\it amp_1}\,\cos \left(2\,{\it freq_1}\,\pi
 \,t+{\it phase_1}\right)}\over{{\it amp_2}}}\right)-2\,{\it freq_2}
 \,\pi\,t \right] $$

$$\left[ {\it phase_3}=\arccos \left({{y}\over{{\it amp_3}}}-{{
 {\it amp_2}\,\cos \left(2\,{\it freq_2}\,\pi\,t+{\it phase_2}\right)
 }\over{{\it amp_3}}}-{{{\it amp_1}\,\cos \left(2\,{\it freq_1}\,\pi
 \,t+{\it phase_1}\right)}\over{{\it amp_3}}}\right)-2\,{\it freq_3}
 \,\pi\,t \right] $$

Image of formula below:
[image: image of formula]

I would like to do a check / calculate phases if given a *freq(x)* and *amp(x)* values.

I know I have to do a for loop but how do I convert this equation into a for loop so it will work on **n groupings** in an array and calculate different values not found in the array?

Basically I would be given an array of **n groupings** and *freq=2.5* and *amp=.23* and use the formula to calculate *phase*.  Note: freq will not always be in the array hence why I'm trying to calculate the *phase(x)* using a formula.

**How would I write the equation / for loop for finding the phase if I want to find freq=2.5 and amp=.23 and the phase is unknown**

One of the suggestions was it may require writing non linear equations which I'm not sure how to convert what I'm trying to do into such an equation any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code (I would use struct arrays as they are nicer and easy to see things but thats for you to learn later)

```
% this is to compute the argument easier you could refactor this part to be more vectorised.
for kk=1:length(a1)   
   cosine_terms(kk) = amp(kk)*cos(2.0 pi freq(kk) + phase(kk);
end
sum_of_cosines = sum(cosine_terms);

for kk=1:length(a1)
    temp_sum = sum_of_cosines - amp(kk)*cos(2.0*pi*freq(kk)+phase(kk);
    phase_test(kk) = arcos((Y-temp_sum)/amp(kk) - 2.0*pi*freq(kk)*t);
end
```

This is code that will probably not run. But I think you get the jist?

Comment: thanks this helps a lot. Any idea how I can use the values of freq=2.5 and amp=.23 and use the formula to calculate the phase? I was trying to alter temp_sum but it has phase already in the equation which I'm trying to solve for, if it's not known.
**How would I write the equation / for loop for finding the phase if I want to find freq=2.5 and amp=.23 and the phase is unknown?**

Comment: hey Rick, you would have to solve a nonlinear set of equations for the phase. This should be handled in the matlab libs ( I tend to write my own code for this).